# Cannot echo the changes made into the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am checking if the files have been modified and I need to echo what new strings have been added. When I try this script for a single file it works, but when I iterate through multiple files in a directory it does not work as it should. Any suggestion?

```
#! /bin/bash

GAP=5

while :
do
    FILES=/home/Desktop/*
    for f in $FILES 
    do
        len=`wc -l $f | awk '{ print $1 }'`

        if [ -N $f ]; then
            echo "`date`: New entries in $f:"
            newlen=`wc -l $f | awk '{ print $1 }'`
            newlines=`expr $newlen - $len`
            tail -$newlines $f
            len=$newlen
        fi
        sleep $GAP
    done
done
```

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way. You will want to use `inotifywait` to watch the files in `/home/bm961355/Desktop/` and then `diff` on any changed files.

Comment: Can you explain me more about that pls? This is how they did the example in the book when you checked a single file so I was based on that, the book did not have any of those commands.

Comment: Watching a directory for changes is easy. the difficult part of your question has to do with determining what lines in a file have changed without having an original of the file to compare against. Your `[ -N "file" ]` would have to be applied to every file in the directory, and then if true, you have no way of telling what is new or changed because there is no original file. If you only want to know if lines have been added or removed, then you can keep an array of the `wc -l` value for each file (but that seems like a waste). I'll give an example of `inotifywait` if you like.

Comment: Isn't any way I can make this code work? Because it is for an assignment and it is required a certain way.

Comment: Sure, but you will need to use a temporary file to hold the `filenames` and `line count` for each file (or if there are less that a couple thousand you can use an array in bash) Before you enter you loop, save the original number of lines for each file and then compare the current line count against the original on each pass through.

Comment: Yeah, we have not learned how to use arrays yet though.

Comment: Oh bummer -- I just finished a slick example with associative arrays... I'll look at one without it. I can post that if you want to work though it while  I look at the other.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you post it. See the thing that is irritating me that it shows the len of each file properly, it shows also that through every loop(it is supposed to run in infinite) the len changes by the same number of string I add but for some reason, the -N flag doesn't work, and it never goes through the if statement.

Comment: The reason the -N isn't working is that when you count the lines in the file, you read it !!  ... so by the time you do the -N test, you've read the file since it last changed.

Comment: You should count the lines with wc *after* the -N test

Comment: @amdn Isn't that what newlen does?

Comment: yes, but you count the number of lines twice, once into len (before -N) and again into newlen (after -N).  The act of invoking `wc` the first time (to assign to len) will indicate to the file system that the file has been read... so the -N will evaluate to false (the file now has been read since last written).

Comment: There's only a slim chance that the file changes between the `wc` that assigns to len (and flags it as read/accessed) and the -N that checks whether it has been written since last read.

Comment: Well the example I based my script in has the same thing and it works perfectly for one file. @amdn

Comment: The example probably sleeps after counting the lines and before testing with -N.  That works fine for one file because you can keep track of its previous length in one variable, len.  The problem with an arbitrary number of files is that you now need to save an arbitrary number of previous lengths, which is why David suggested an associative array or a temporary file to hold all those counts.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I do not have all those means in my disposal, that's why I am trying to stick to this script.

Comment: Well, the alternatives are pretty ugly... you could copy the entire directory you are watching to another directory, then loop through the files looking for one that changes using -N, then count the lines in the duplicate directory (with the old length)... but I doubt that is acceptable.

Comment: That's what I did thanks to Mr. David. Well, that's what my professor asked, can't blame me.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the comments, here is the original solution I envisioned using `inotifywait` (from the `inotify-tools` package) and an associative array. The benefit here is `inotifywait` will block and will not waste resources endlessly checking the line count of each file on each loop iteration. I'll work on a solution using a temporary file, but when you go that route you open yourself up to a change occurring in between loop iterations. Here is the first solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

watchdir="${1:-$PWD}"
events="-e modify -e attrib -e close_write -e create -e delete -e move"
declare -A lines

for i in "$watchdir"/*; do
    [ -f "$i" ] && lines[$i]=$(wc -l <"$i")
done

while :; do  ## watch for changes in chosen dir
    fname="${watchdir}/$(inotifywait -q $events --format '%f' "$watchdir")"
    newlc=$(wc -l <"$fname")  ## get line count for changed file
    if [ "${lines[$fname]}" -ne "$newlc" ]; then    ## if changed, print
        printf " lines chanaged : %s -> %s (%s)\n" \
        "${lines[$fname]}" "$newlc" "$fname"
        lines[$fname]=$newlc  ## update saved line count for file
    fi
done
```

**Original testfile.txt**

```
$ cat dat/tmp/testfile.txt
 1 1.2
 2 2.2
```

**Example Use/Output**

Script saved in `watchdir.sh`. Start `watchdir.sh` so `inotifywait` is watching the `dat/tmp` directory

```
$ ./watchdir.sh dat/tmp
```

Using a second terminal, modify file in the `dat/tmp` directory

```
$ echo "newline" >> ~/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/testfile.txt
$ echo "newline" >> ~/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/testfile.txt
```

Output of watchdir.sh running in separate terminal (or background)

```
$ ./watchdir.sh dat/tmp
 lines chanaged : 2 -> 3 (dat/tmp/testfile.txt)
 lines chanaged : 3 -> 4 (dat/tmp/testfile.txt)
```

Resulting `testfile.txt`

```
$ cat dat/tmp/testfile.txt
 1 1.2
 2 2.2
newline
newline
```

**Second Solution Using [ -N file ]**

Here is a second solution a bit closer to your first attempt. It is a less robust way to approach the solution (it will miss multiple changes between tests, etc.). Look it over and let me know if you have questions

```
#!/bin/bash

watchdir="${1:-$PWD}"
gap=5
tmpfile="$TMPDIR/watchtmp"  ## temp file in system $TMPDIR (/tmp)
:>"$tmpfile"

trap 'rm $tmpfile' SIGTERM EXIT ## remove tmpfile on exit

for i in "$watchdir"/*; do      ## populate tmpfile with line counts
    [ -f "$i" ] && echo "$i,$(wc -l <"$i")" >> "$tmpfile"
done

while :; do                                 ## loop every $gap seconds
    for i in "$watchdir"/*; do              ## for each file
        if [ -N "$i" ]; then                ## check changed
            cnt=$(wc -l <"$i")              ## get new line count
            oldcnt=$(grep "$i" "$tmpfile")  ## get old count
            oldcnt=${oldcnt##*,}
            if [ "$cnt" -ne "$oldcnt" ]; then  ## if not equal, print
                printf " lines chanaged : %s -> %s (%s)\n" \
                "$oldcnt" "$cnt" "$i"
                ## update tmpfile with new count
                sed -i "s|^${i}[,][0-9][0-9]*.*$|${i},$cnt|" "$tmpfile"
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $gap
done
```

**Use/Output**

Start watchdir.sh

```
$ ./watchdir2.sh dat/tmp
```

In second terminal modify file

```
$ echo "newline" >> ~/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/testfile.txt
```

wait for `$gap` to expire (if changed twice - it will not register)

```
$ echo "newline" >> ~/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/testfile.txt
```

Results

```
$ ./watchdir2.sh dat/tmp
 lines chanaged : 10 -> 11 (dat/tmp/testfile.txt)
 lines chanaged : 11 -> 12 (dat/tmp/testfile.txt)
```

Comment: This looks fine, but I doubt this is what I need, since apparently you need to install the program 'inotifywait'. I should prob stick to [ -N $f ]

Comment: @J.Doe Really? This is a sticky problem which is finally solved robustly with `inotifywait` -- if you want to stay with shell scripts, you have a great career in the yak shaving business waiting for you.

Comment: @tripleee I am not saying that sticking to [ -N $f ] is the better, but I have requirements to follow. Considering the fact that in my book so far 'inotifywait' is never mentioned I doubt my professor will agree to this solution.

Comment: Btw, in the -N example, what is this line "tmpfile="$TMPDIR/watchtmp" means exactly? Because when I run it it gives me /watchtmp: Permission Denied error.

Comment: What that means is you have no `$TMPDIR` set which is common to most (if not all) Linux distributions. You can either add `TMPDIR=/tmp` just above that line, or change the directory to somewhere you can write to (not in the directory you are watching). For example `tmpfile="$HOME/watchtmp"` (do `echo $HOME` to make sure that is set to something reasonable)

Comment: That is amazing, thanks a lot for all the help!! One last question; if I wanted to print the actual lines that I added to the file, instead of the number lines of the lines added, what approach should I take?

Comment: `tail -n+${oldcnt} "$i"` That will print the line number `$oldcnt` to end of file -- including your new line. You can use `tail -n+${cnt} "$i"` if you only want the last line, or `tail -n 1 "$i"` as well. You can also print the exact line with `sed -n "$cnt"p`

Comment: Glad to help. Everybody needs a hand up when they first start any language. You will enjoy bash. It is incredibly capable, with excellent file and string manipulation handling, arrays will usually take the place of tmp-files, etc.. I know *man bash* looks a little Greek, but make friends with it. It actually has all of the information you need in that one-stop shop. However,, I also recall not liking it that much when I first started with shell -- but it is 100% worth taking the time to get familiar with it.